# Hardback 80s UK comic with 2 stories, one sci-fi, one fantasy, ends with a peasant uprising singing about the fight "for freedom"

Tags: story-identification, comics

Trying to find a comic book/graphic novel that I read when I was a kid. Probably came out in the early 80s but possible earlier or a little later, probably by a UK publisher.

I believe it had two stories. One was a sci-fi one that I think I really liked, but can't actually remember, which is mostly why I want to find this. The other was a fantasy story that I don't remember *much* better... except for the last panel.

I think the main character was a Prince (in a fantasy story? So distinct!), and at the end he had managed to break a bunch of peasants/slaves out... I don't *think* he actually beat the big-bad, but I could be wrong.

The big thing I remember is the final page of the fantasy story. It was (I think) a full-page panel with the Prince walking towards the page, and the peasants following him. The text on the page started with the narrator saying that he he would "continue the fight...", which diagetically transitions to the peasants singing "for freeeeeeeeedom".